# html and PHP Array control

Tags: php, html, arrays, web, radio-button

I have a form set up via HTML in one page that executes another page via php

It contains several radio buttons each corresponding to an option the user can select, how would I pass which option the user selected over to my 2nd file and allow it to use that data?

Im guessing it has something to do with values but searches are not helping.

This is what the radio buttons on my first page look like:

```
<input type="radio" name="radbed[0]" id="radsingletwin" value="radsingletwin">
```

There is a radio button for each option (5 in total)

The two Arrays in my 2nd page/file.

```
$BedInfo = array(
    "Single Twin Bed",
    "Two Single Twin Beds",
    "Queen Bed",
    "Two Queen Beds",
    "King Bed"
); 

$BedCost = array(95.00,115.00,115.00,150.00,125.00);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would output you array into your radio buttons and then pass that value

```
$BedInfo = array("Single Twin Bed", "Two Single Twin Beds", "Queen Bed", "Two Queen Beds", "King Bed");
foreach($BedInfo as $bed) {
    echo '<input type="radio" name="bed" value="' . $bed . '" />' . $bed . '<br/>';
}
```

On your processing page I would have

```
$BedCost = array("Single Twin Bed" => 95.00, "Two Single Twin Beds" => 115.00, "Queen Bed" => 115.00, "Two Queen Beds" => 150.00, "King Bed" => 125);
if(!isset($BedCost[$_POST['bed']]) { 
    echo 'Bad value';
} else {
    echo 'Your bed costs $' . $BedCost[$_POST['bed']];
}
```